# Is it possible to limit Flask POST data size on a per-route basis?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am aware it is possible to [set an overall limit on request size](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/fileuploads/) in Flask with:

```
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024
```

BUT I want to ensure that one specific route will not accept POST data over a certain size.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You'll need to check this for the specific route itself; you can always test the content length; [`request.content_length`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.CommonRequestDescriptorsMixin.content_length) is either `None` or an integer value:

```
cl = request.content_length
if cl is not None and cl > 3 * 1024 * 1024:
    abort(413)
```

Do this before accessing form or file data on the request.

You can make this into a decorator for your views:

```
from functools import wraps
from flask import request, abort


def limit_content_length(max_length):
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            cl = request.content_length
            if cl is not None and cl > max_length:
                abort(413)
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

then use this as:

```
@app.route('/...')
@limit_content_length(3 * 1024 * 1024)
def your_view():
    # ...
```

This is *essentially* what Flask does; when you try to access request data, the Content-Length header is checked first before attempting to parse the request body. With the decorator or manual check you just made the same test, but a little earlier in the view lifecycle.